# FileUpload.hasFile is always False

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have a `FileUpload` control (and it's not inside an `UpdatePanel`) and its `hasFile` property is always `False`.

```
   <asp:FileUpload ID="certificateUploader" runat="server"/>
```

Any thought?

Comment: Be clear in your question. What happens exactly

Comment: when i click on the browse and browse for file, select one and hit open, i can see the path of the file right on the fileUploader control, when i hit  the Save button(customzied for my app) i check if it .hasFile it returns False each and everytime.

Comment: i've edited my Question with more code except for the last two lines that couldnt been copied

Answer (score 60):

Add a trigger for your UpdatePanel

```
<Triggers>
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCertificateUpload" />
</Triggers>
```

This will force a postback when the upload button is clicked.

Also, add the line below to the Page_Load

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

Comment: will definitly give it a try :)

Comment: And what about the same problem with a FileUpload that isn't inside an UpdatePanel (as the question says)?

Comment: If someone new about Update Panel and FileUpload find this answer from a search engine (like me), take a look to this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/fileupload-control-in-update-panel-using-Asp-Net-ajax/
It also helped me. Anyway, thanks for your short but eficient answer

Comment: Why is this the correct answer when the question clearly says that the file upload IS NOT in an update panel?!

Comment: @Santhos Maybe because it turned out that it is indeed in an update panel? Like when the update panel is in a Master Page? Like what happened to me?

Comment: Because it's Ajax, will not work with the asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger or Async postback. That is why you have to specifically tell the update panel to use asp:PostBackTrigger. This makes it work, but you loose the nifty seamless partial page post. I abandoned the fileupload control and went with a jquery/javascript solution posting to ASP.NET webhandler. .ashx

Answer (score 17):

You cannot upload files using AJAX => you should not be placing a FileUpload control inside an UpdatePanel because this UpdatePanel sends an AJAX request to the server.

Comment: </asp:UpdatePanel>
       <asp:FileUpload ID="certificateUploader" runat="server"/>

Comment: This was my issue! Thanks a lot. I didn't even have the file uploader in the update panel but my update panel had the submit button of the page as an async trigger.

Answer (score 16):

I also uploaded a file using the FileUpload control, but the HasFile property returned false. Turn out that FileUpload.HasFile is also false if you upload an empty file. In this case, adding some text to the file, you want to upload will make the Has file property return true.

Comment: Faced the same issue.

Comment: Right! Same issue for me, thanks.

Answer (score 11):

To complement the example given by @dbFrameIT Support:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button ID="UploadButton" runat="server" Text="Upload Selected File" OnClick="UploadButton_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="UploadDetails" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadButton" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

your code behind (c#)

```
    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile == false)
        {
            UploadDetails.Text = "Please first select a file to upload...";
        }
        else
        {
            string FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
            UploadDetails.Text = string.Format(
                    @"Uploaded file: {0}<br />
              File size (in bytes): {1:N0}<br />
              Content-type: {2}",
                      FileName,
                      FileUpload1.FileBytes.Length,
                      FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType);

            // Save the file
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Brochures/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

the whole time it was about the permissions i had(or didn't have to be more specific) over the file am trying to upload, i granted the user the sufficient permissions and it all went well.

thanks a lot for your help and posts.

Comment: could you expand, think I am facing the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes fileUpload has problems. You can use simple input:

```
<input id="filMyFile" type="file" runat="server"></input>
```

In code save file to server:

```
HttpPostedFile myFile = filMyFile.PostedFile;           
string fullPath=Server.MapPath("~/UploadDocuments/") + myFile.FileName;
myFile.SaveAs(fullPath);
```

And file will save at UploadDocuments folder in your ASP.NET application (server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take your button off from the UpdatePanel;
As far as I get, UpdatePanels always update when something inside any other update panel updates, so if your button postback, your FileUpload control also postback and lose the file reference.