# FileUploader.Has File always returning false in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

i have been working trying to find the answers for this but i cant find any solutions that worked.

```
MultipleFileUploader.ascx:
     <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>  
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
                    multiple="multiple" onchange="__doPostBack('<%= UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>', ''); type="file" />
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Behind Codes:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            onAttach();
    }
```

It uploads the file the moment the user selects a file with the Postback __doPostBack
It shouldnt be browser issue because im getting the same problem on chrome firefox and IE. 
The codes has always been working fine till we upgraded to .net 4.0, for some reason it FileUploader.HasFile always return false.

I have tried:

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

and :

```
<Triggers> 
   <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" /> 
</Triggers>
```

Am i missing something simple or anything? 
Any help rendered is very much appreciated. 
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you placed the trigger inside `<update panel>` like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1"  runat="server">
  <Triggers> 
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadFile" /> 
  </Triggers> 
 <rest of the code>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Taken from this post [FileUpload.hasFile is always False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682737/fileupload-hasfile-is-always-false)

If it's still not working then try placing your FileUpload control outside `UpdatePanel` and see if it works. Reasoning: you should not be placing a `FileUpload` control inside an `UpdatePanel` because the `UpdatePanel` sends an AJAX request to the server.

Make sure that the credential using which you are running web application has access to the file. In other words `it's not a file permission issue`.

you can also use `FileUpload` controls `FileName` property like

```
if (FileUpload1.FileName != string.Empty)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Its not a file permission issue. 

Tried(FileUpload1.FileName) - Its still returning string.Empty. 

I realised that i cant put the triggers based on the button because the method is triggered by PageLoad event, which is triggered when the uploader is changed. __DoPostBack <- Does a postback, and in the postbackEvent i check if the file is uploaded.

I suspect its some .net 4.0 Issue.

Comment: @JoshuaTan, have you tried placing the `FileUpload` control outside `updatepanel`?

Comment: OH Wao, It worked outside of the update panel! Thank you! However i need it to be in the update panel, is there a way around this, I'm still finding it very mysterious as to whats happening? But really happy that it worked, thank you very much

Comment: @JoshuaTan, as of now I am out of idea but I have edited my answer by putting the reason behind placing it outside. Please don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped by clicking the check button below voting button

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, im sorry i would definitely up vote you if i had 15 rep or more. but please know that i appreciate your time and effort. Kudos to smart and kind ppl like you =D

Comment: @JoshuaTan, you don't need to upvote but you can accept the answer. Below voting buton there is a check mark button present .. by clicking that