# asp FileUpload.HasFile is set to false after uploading but when refresh is set to true

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Sorry for this question but I'm working this problem for an hour for now, can't really figure this out.

After uploading images, I dispose my fileupload so its property (hasfile) will be set to false. But when I refresh the page, it comes to have a file again and that's why my file is uploaded twice. Here's my code:

if (file1.HasFile)
                {
                    file1.SaveAs(MapPath("~/MyFolder/Hi.jpg"));
                    file1.PostedFile.InputStream.Close();
                    file1.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose();
                    file1.Dispose();
                }

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I doubt you have done this but just to be sure. you aren't calling your upload method in `Page_Load` or any `onLoad` are you? I'm not even sure if this could cause your problem.

Comment: No, this method isn't in my page load, it's on my button_click..

Comment: You should read this if you use UpdatePanel.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682737/fileupload-hasfile-is-always-false