# Upload button not uploading Image File ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, image-uploading

```
<div style="width: 90%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; text-align:center">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        DataKeyNames="immersionID" GridLines="Horizontal" 
        OnRowCommand="GridView4Data_RowCommand" onpageindexchanging="GridView4_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn"
                  ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Record">
                 <ControlStyle CssClass="btn"></ControlStyle>
            </asp:ButtonField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="immersionID" HeaderText="Immersion ID" 
                SortExpression="immersionID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="immersionName" HeaderText="Immersion Name" 
                SortExpression="immersionName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="startDate" HeaderText="Start Date" 
                SortExpression="startDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="endDate" HeaderText="End Date " />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="noOfParticipants" HeaderText="No Of Participants" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="File Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download Link" 
                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload2" runat="server" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("immersionID") %>' OnClick="DownloadFile4" 
                        Text="Download"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image1" ItemStyle-Height="150" 
                ItemStyle-Width="170">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITimage") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image10" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ITimage", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
                <ItemStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITimage2") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image11" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ITimage2", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
                <ItemStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image3">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITimage3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image12" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ITimage3", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
                <ItemStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image4" SortExpression="ITimage4">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITimage4") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ITimage4", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
                <ItemStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image5" SortExpression="ITimage5">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ITimage5") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ITimage5", GetUrl("{0}")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ControlStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
                <ItemStyle Height="170px" Width="150px" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="No Record Found"></asp:Label>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000000" />
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>    
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                 <table width="100%" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="color:Black;"
                    align="center">

                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h3>Details</h3> 
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 45%; text-align: center;">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelValidate" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width: 45%">
                    Immersion ID:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="width: 45%">
                    Immersion Name:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBName" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Immersion Description:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Immersion Location:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBLocation" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Immersion Country:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBCountry" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Category:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="TBCat" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Select a Category</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Category A</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Category B</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    No. Of Participants:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBNumber" runat="server" />

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Start Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBStart" runat="server" type="date"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    End Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBEnd" runat="server" type="date"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Remarks:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Submitted By:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="TBSubmit" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Diploma:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TBDip" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Attachment:</td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload19" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Image 1: </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload20" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Image 2: </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload21" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Image 3: </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload22" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Image 4: </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload23" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    Image 5: </td>
                <td class="style11">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload24" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

                 <div class="modal-footer">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" class="btn" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
                 <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView4" EventName="RowCommand" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </div>

</div>
```

Above is my code for my webform page. This webform page inherits my master page where it has another form tag. 
I'm doing a pop-up within the page to prompt user to update their data.

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TBName.Text == "" && TBDesc.Text == "" && TBLocation.Text == "" &&
            TBCountry.Text == "" && TBCat.Text == "" &&
            TBNumber.Text == "" && TBStart.Text == "" && TBEnd.Text == "" &&
            TBRemarks.Text == "" && TBDip.Text == "")
        {
            LabelValidate.Text = "Please enter all details.";
            LabelValidate.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE ImmersionTrip set immersionName=@immersionName, immersionDesc=@immersionDesc, immersionLocation=@immersionLocation, immersionCountry=@immersionCountry, category=@category, noOfParticipants=@noOfParticipants, startDate=@startDate, endDate=@endDate, remarks=@remarks, itDiplomas=@itDiplomas where immersionID= '" + int.Parse(lblID.Text) + "'", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionID", lblID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionName", TBName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionDesc", TBDesc.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionLocation", TBLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionCountry", TBCountry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", TBCat.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@noOfParticipants", TBNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", TBStart.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", TBEnd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", TBRemarks.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itDiplomas", TBDip.Text);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (FileUpload19.HasFile)
            {
                upload1();
            }
            if (FileUpload20.HasFile)
            {
                upload2();
            }
            if (FileUpload21.HasFile)
            {
                upload3();
            }

            if (FileUpload22.HasFile)
            {
                upload4();
            }

            if (FileUpload23.HasFile)
            {
                upload5();
            }

            if (FileUpload24.HasFile)
            {
                upload6();
            }


            BindGrid4();
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("alert('Records Updated Successfully');");
            sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('hide');");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
            lblresult.Text = TBName.Text + "'s" + " details updated successfully!";
            lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditHideModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
            //Popup(false);
        }

        this.RegisterPostBackControl();

    }




    void Popup(bool isDisplay)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        if (isDisplay)
        {
            builder.Append("<script language=JavaScript> ShowPopup(); </script>\n");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", builder.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Append("<script language=JavaScript> HidePopup(); </script>\n");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HidePopup", builder.ToString());
        }
    }
private void upload1()
    {
        string filenameI;
        string contentType = FileUpload19.PostedFile.ContentType;
        if (FileUpload19.HasFile)
        {
            filenameI = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload19.PostedFile.FileName);
        }
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload19.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET Fname = @Fname , ContentType = @contentType , Data =@Data " + "WHERE immersionID = @immersionID;";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@immersionID", lblID.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FileUpload19.FileName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        BindGrid4();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void upload2()
    {
        if (FileUpload20.HasFile)
        {
            string imageFile20 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload20.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload20.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images1/") + imageFile20);
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images1/");
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload20.FileContent);
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 150;
            int newHeight = 170;
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            newBMP.Save(directory + imageFile20);
            originalBMP.Dispose();
            newBMP.Dispose();
            oGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        SqlConnection connection13 = new SqlConnection();
        connection13.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Star.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            connection13.Open();
            string sqlStmt13 = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET ITimage = '" + "Images1/" + FileUpload20.FileName + "' WHERE immersionID = '" + lblID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd13 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt13, connection13);
            cmd13.CommandText = sqlStmt13;
            cmd13.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection13.Close();
            BindGrid4();
        }
    }

    private void upload3()
    {
        if (FileUpload21.HasFile)
        {
            string imageFile21 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload21.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload21.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images1/") + imageFile21);
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images1/");
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload21.FileContent);
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 150;
            int newHeight = 170;
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            newBMP.Save(directory + imageFile21);
            originalBMP.Dispose();
            newBMP.Dispose();
            oGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        SqlConnection connection14 = new SqlConnection();
        connection14.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Star.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            connection14.Open();
            string sqlStmt14 = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET ITimage2 = '" + "Images1/" + FileUpload21.FileName + "' WHERE immersionID = '" + lblID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd14 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt14, connection14);
            cmd14.CommandText = sqlStmt14;
            cmd14.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection14.Close();
            BindGrid4();
        }
    }

    private void upload4()
    {
        if (FileUpload22.HasFile)
        {
            string imageFile22 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload22.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload22.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images1/") + imageFile22);
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images1/");
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload22.FileContent);
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 150;
            int newHeight = 170;
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            newBMP.Save(directory + imageFile22);
            originalBMP.Dispose();
            newBMP.Dispose();
            oGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        SqlConnection connection15 = new SqlConnection();
        connection15.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Star.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            connection15.Open();
            string sqlStmt15 = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET ITimage3 = '" + "Images1/" + FileUpload22.FileName + "' WHERE immersionID = '" + lblID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd15 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt15, connection15);
            cmd15.CommandText = sqlStmt15;
            cmd15.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection15.Close();
            BindGrid4();
        }
    }

    private void upload5()
    {
        if (FileUpload23.HasFile)
        {
            string imageFile23 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload23.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload23.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images1/") + imageFile23);
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images1/");
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload23.FileContent);
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 150;
            int newHeight = 170;
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            newBMP.Save(directory + imageFile23);
            originalBMP.Dispose();
            newBMP.Dispose();
            oGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        SqlConnection connection16 = new SqlConnection();
        connection16.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Star.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            connection16.Open();
            string sqlStmt16 = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET ITimage4 = '" + "Images1/" + FileUpload23.FileName + "' WHERE immersionID = '" + lblID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd16 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt16, connection16);
            cmd16.CommandText = sqlStmt16;
            cmd16.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection16.Close();
            BindGrid4();
        }
    }

    private void upload6()
    {
        if (FileUpload24.HasFile)
        {
            string imageFile24 = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload24.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload24.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images1/") + imageFile24);
            string directory = Server.MapPath(@"~/Images1/");
            Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(FileUpload24.FileContent);
            int origWidth = originalBMP.Width;
            int origHeight = originalBMP.Height;
            int sngRatio = origWidth / origHeight;
            int newWidth = 150;
            int newHeight = 170;
            Bitmap newBMP = new Bitmap(originalBMP, newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBMP);
            oGraphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; oGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            oGraphics.DrawImage(originalBMP, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            newBMP.Save(directory + imageFile24);
            originalBMP.Dispose();
            newBMP.Dispose();
            oGraphics.Dispose();
        }
        SqlConnection connection17 = new SqlConnection();
        connection17.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Star.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
        try
        {
            connection17.Open();
            string sqlStmt17 = "UPDATE ImmersionTrip SET ITimage5 = '" + "Images1/" + FileUpload24.FileName + "' WHERE immersionID = '" + lblID.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd17 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt17, connection17);
            cmd17.CommandText = sqlStmt17;
            cmd17.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            connection17.Close();
            BindGrid4();
        }
    }
```

Above is my code-behind to upload the image into my database.

*All the other fields are able to be updated, e.g. Date and event name etc

There isn't any error when i click the upload button, and I've already tried debugging it, and apparently it skips all the upload method even if i have a file selected in each field.

So the problem is I'm not able to upload the images into database. Please help resolve this, help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682737/fileupload-hasfile-is-always-false   basically your condition is always false because its set at page load and never updated.

Comment: OMG thank you so much Unicorno Marley, you're my savior! It works amazingly.

Apparently its my trigger event that has an error, i used async instead of just postback.