# on using ajax, asp.net button control click event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax with asp.net C#. What I am trying to do is, on click of a link, a `div` should appear. A `div` contains file upload controls and a button named 'Upload Files'. When upload files button is clicked, it is checking if any of the file upload controls has files. If yes, it uploads files to some directory and updates a label to show how many files are uploaded 0 or more. Here is the screenshot to explain: 
[image: Link (Insert More Attachments is clicked then file upload controls are visible and even after I select the files, button always displays message 0 file(s) uploaded)]

Here's the code snippet, I am using Ajax with asp.net C#

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1" updatemode="Conditional">           
            <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <% if (Session["MemberID"]!= null)
                       {%>                   
                       <asp:LinkButton ID="insertMore" runat="server" OnClick="insertMoreclicked">(Insert More Attachments)</asp:LinkButton>
                      <%} %>

                </div><br />

                <div id="moreUploadsDiv" runat="server" visible="false">
                <br />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="moreUpload1" runat="server" />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="moreUpload2" runat="server" />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="moreUpload3" runat="server" />
                <asp:FileUpload ID="moreUpload4" runat="server" />

                <asp:Button ID="uploadMoreFilesBtn" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick ="uploadMoreClicked" CausesValidation="false" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="uploadInfoLbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

             </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here's the code behind file event for button:

```
protected void uploadMoreClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int countFiles = 0;
     if (moreUpload1.HasFile)
     {
         moreUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Upload/") + moreUpload1.FileName);
         string fn2 = moreUpload1.FileName;
         bool status2 = blReg.insertFiles(fn2, FileID);

         countFiles++;
     }
     if (moreUpload2.HasFile)
     {
         moreUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Upload/") + moreUpload2.FileName);
         string fn2 = moreUpload2.FileName;
         bool status2 = blReg.insertFiles(fn2, FileID);

         countFiles++;
     }
     if (moreUpload3.HasFile)
     {
         moreUpload3.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Upload/") + moreUpload3.FileName);
         string fn2 = moreUpload3.FileName;
         bool status2 = blReg.insertFiles(fn2, FileID);

         countFiles++;
     }
     if (moreUpload4.HasFile)
     {
         moreUpload4.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Upload/") + moreUpload4.FileName);
         string fn2 = moreUpload4.FileName;
         bool status2 = blReg.insertFiles(fn2, FileID);

         countFiles++;
     }
     uploadInfoLbl.Text = countFiles + " file(s) uploaded<br/>";
}
```

But button click event doesn't work. Please suggest me what i am doing wrong. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are you sure its not working? Can you put a break point at the top of your uploadMoreClicked method and see if the code is posting back?

Comment: I checked, it is going to click event, In the click event, even after uploading files, FileUpload.HasFile conditions are not true. @Matt

Comment: Hard to tell without physcially having the code but; I suppose its possible that the file upload has completed before you click uplaod, and thus it is empty again?
Or because you are clicking an upload button, not the FileUpload button, that it doesn't actually think it has a file?
Out of interest, can you add a trigger event for one of the upload controls to the update panel, and see if that gives you the right information?

Comment: there are several answers that might help you sort this out here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682737/fileupload-hasfile-is-always-false